# Open file at given path with non-default program?

Tags: windows-7, pdf, adobe-acrobat, pdf-reader

I am normally opening PDF files with Foxit Reader.

Now I have one PDF file (C:\sample.pdf) which I edit quite often, so for opening it, I am always using Adobe Acrobat. Currently I always have to right click this file, choose open with and then Adobe Acrobat. Is it possible, to tell Windows, that just for this one PDF file (C:\sample.pdf) Adobe Acrobat shall be the default program and not Foxit Reader?

I know I could build some batch file starting Adobe Acrobat with C:\sample.pdf as parameter. Yet I am wondering if there is any direct way, to change the default program for a given file?

Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen any windows system outside of specific programs, like filezilla that can do this, the file type associations are per extention not per file. The only work around i know of is to open the program you want then use that program specifically to open that one file.

Doing it this way you have to remember yourself which program you want which file opening but if its only for the occasional file its workable because there is normally a recent files option in the program menus.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Adobe Acrobat so not sure how well it will respond to this. Try it and let me know.

Ensure file extensions are visible in Windows Explorer and rename **OddFile.*pdf*** to **OddFile.*pda*** or other unused extension, then simply associate .PDA files with Acrobat. Now double-clicking **OddFile.pda** will open it with Acrobat and all should be well, as long as the program has no issues opening/saving PDFs with unrecognised extensions. (You *might* need to specify the file name in quotes though while saving, as in "OddFile.pda", so that Acrobat doesn't save it as OddFile.pda.pdf instead.)

This is the best you can do IMO short of creating a batch file.